# JPA - not member of query looks for bigint instead of date?

Tags: java, database, jpa, netbeans

Querying my jpa database (using netbeans, glassfish) with the following query works:

```
//assume java.sql.Date d
Query q = em.createQuery("select b from Band b where :date MEMBER OF b.dates");
q.setParameter("date", d);
List bands = q.getResultList();
```

However, when I change the MEMBER OF to NOT MEMBER OF I get the following server error:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'DATE' from a data value of type 'BIGINT'.
Error Code: 20000
Call: SELECT t0.ID, t0.DTYPE, t0.EMAIL, t0.NAME, t0.PASSWORD, t0.BIOGRAPHY, t0.PHONENUMBER FROM SUPERUSER t0 WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT t2.ID FROM SUPERUSER t2, Band_DATES t1 WHERE ((((t1.Band_ID = t0.ID) AND (? = t2.ID)) AND (t2.DTYPE = ?)) AND (t2.DTYPE = ?)))  AND (t0.DTYPE = ?))
bind => [4 parameters bound]
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using sql.Date's everywhere.

Edit: including my Band entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BAND")
public class Band extends SuperUser{
@Column(name="PHONENUMBER")
private String phoneNumber;
@Column(name="BIOGRAPHY")
private String biography;

@Column(name="DATES", columnDefinition = "DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE")
@ElementCollection 
private List<Date> dates = new <Date>ArrayList();

public Band(){}

public Band(String n, String e, String p, String ph_no, String bio){
    super(n,e,p);  
    this.phoneNumber = ph_no;
    this.biography = bio;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String p)
{
    this.phoneNumber = p;
}
public String getPhoneNumber()
{
    return this.phoneNumber;
}
public void setBoigraphy(String b)
{
    this.biography = b;
}
public String getBiography()
{
    return this.biography;
}
public void setDate(Date d)
{
    dates.add(d);
}
public void cancelDate(Date d)
{
    while(dates.remove(d))
    {}
}
public List getDates()
{
    return dates;
}

}
```

How does one obtain a table description?

Comment: Please post your entity and table description.

Comment: Entity posted, I have no idea how to get a table description in netbeans.

Comment: How are you expecting to get `List<Date>` from a single column? I assume the dates are stored in another database table, in which case you need `@CollectionTable`

Comment: could you elaborate? I Thought I could save the list containing the dates in one column.

Comment: "The ElementCollection values are always stored in a separate table." From: [the wikibooks article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection)

Comment: So Why would it work with member of? surely to work with the positive, my annotations must be working?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL does not look valid, it is most likely an issue with using MEMBER OF.  You might want to try the latest release of your JPA provider or log a bug, although I'm not sure if the MEMBER OF syntax is allowed for ElementCollection.

MEMBER OF is an old JPQL (from EJBQL) syntax, it is normally better to use JOIN in JPQL now.

Try,

```
select b from Band b join b.dates d where d = :date
```

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate your `dates` @ElementCollection with the @Temporal annotation. As well, when using @ElementCollection I do not think you can use @Column but rather @CollectionTable if you want to specify names of columns. Just this should work though:

```
@ElementCollection 
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private List<Date> dates = new <Date>ArrayList();
```